# How Do I Know Change Directory System Watcher?

Tags: vb.net

How do I change directory folder in system watcher?

I made a desktop app to upload file in database.

I set the root folder as `C:\Users\x\Desktop\Test`. 
A user can copy/paste a file into that folder and that file will upload to database.
but sometimes, a user can upload not in that root folder. user can upload file to other folder in root.

Let's say in the root folder, there are folders called `Hello` and `Hallo`..
the user clicks on the folder Hello, directory change not C:\Users\x\Desktop\Test again but `C:\Users\x\Desktop\Test\Hello`

My question, how can I detect it?
Because system watcher can only handle created, changed, deleted, renamed. So I must change or create file first to get `e.fullpath`.

I want that if I click folder `Hello`, I get `e.fullpath` :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `IncludeSubdirectories` property on your `FileSystemWatcher` to true, e.g.:

```
fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = True
```

Ref: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.includesubdirectories(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.includesubdirectories%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: i have set that property before..
the problem is when i click folder Hello,i can't get the directory before i changed first..
i want if i click folder Hello,i get that directory (C:\User\x\Desktop\Test\Hello)
can you help me?
thanks